Как решить ошибку «type=AAAA: Host not found»?
При отправке письма с почтового ящика яндекса в почтовый ящик test@cubinez85.local получаю ошибку :
```<test@cubinez85.local>: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=cubinez85.local type=AAAA: Host not found```
На сервере,где установлен postfix, dovecot и roundcube, также установлен Bind. Где на ip vm прописаны 2 домена:
cubinez.ru (реальный домен с записями в reg.ru) и виртуальный домен cubinez85.local, на котором установлен почтовый ящик test@cubinez85.local
```~$ nslookup 10.128.0.34
34.0.128.10.in-addr.arpa        name = cubinez85.local.
34.0.128.10.in-addr.arpa        name = cubinez.ru.```

```cubinez85@cubinez:~$ nslookup cubinez85.local
Server:         10.128.0.34
Address:        10.128.0.34#53

Name:   cubinez85.local
Address: 10.128.0.100
Name:   cubinez85.local
Address: 10.128.0.34```

```cubinez85@cubinez:~$ dig PTR cubinez85.local

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> PTR cubinez85.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35411
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: efe8b4f0898ce8a701000000666855c61c3c51a4ab0d2075 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;cubinez85.local.               IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cubinez85.local.        604800  IN      SOA     cubinez85.local. admin.cubinez85.local. 3 604800 86400 2419200 604800

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.128.0.34#53(10.128.0.34) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 16:48:54 MSK 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114```

```cubinez85@cubinez:~$ dig aaaa yandex.ru

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> aaaa yandex.ru
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57537
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 78add350459813ef0100000066685603708672d7ba9540d5 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yandex.ru.                     IN      AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yandex.ru.              118     IN      AAAA    2a02:6b8:a::a

;; Query time: 84 msec
;; SERVER: 10.128.0.34#53(10.128.0.34) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 16:49:55 MSK 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 94```

```cubinez85@cubinez:~$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 3.6
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mydomain = cubinez.ru
myhostname = cubinez.ru
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = $mynetworks
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/cubinez.ru/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/cubinez.ru/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:1024
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 1024
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:1024```

```/etc/postfix/main.cf
inet_protocols = ipv4```

```cubinez85@cubinez:~$ sudo cat /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.128.0.34
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search cubinez.ru
search cubinez85.local```
Чего не так?


1- ящик нужно создать на реальном домене, не на виртуальном
2- пользователя(имя ящика) нужно прописать в базе данных (в моем случае mysql) и в конфигах postfix
